# Loosing type safety or not loosing type safety

Tags: typescript, types

Anybody can able to explain me what is the difference between those two versions of declaring `status` property? I know that in some why the second version not loose type safety, but how does it work?

```
export type OwnProps = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  status: 'draft' | 'completed';
};
```

and

```
status: Union(Literal('draft'), Literal('completed')),
```

The library which delivers `Union`, `Literal` (any many more): https://github.com/pelotom/runtypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That library is for runtime validation of types, not for the typing itself (though you can use the types that it outputs as well). It allows you to check if an object actually conforms to a type specification which has to be done using the functions of the library like `Union` and `Literal`. You should read the documentation of the library.